# I'm trying to close the offcanvas menu in React Bootstrap when I click a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using a combination of React Bootstrap and React, to make a single page application, I've tried a few methods to get the Offcanvas menu to close when I click a link. I tried making an inline script on the link that toggles the menu, but what I found is the menu closes as I want it to but then the link only takes me halfway to where it should navigate to.

this is my code so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, Offcanvas } from "react-bootstrap";
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background-color: #9ac2ba;
  .Nav-Brand {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar {
    background-color: #9ac2ba;
  }
`;

const LinkWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  .nav-link {
    color: #333;
  }
  .nav-link:hover {
    color: #000;
  }
`;

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Navbar
        as="nav"
        variant="light"
        fixed="top"
        expand={false}
        className="shadow"
      >
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="/" className="Nav-Brand">
            <StaticImage
              src="../images/Spf-Brand-01.jpg"
              alt="Brand Image"
              layout="constrained"
              placeholder="blurred"
              height={50}
              loading="eager"
            />
            <h1 className="visually-hidden">
              SPF Paint &amp; Decorating, Birmingham
            </h1>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle
            aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar"
            aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
          />
          <Navbar.Offcanvas id="offcanvasNavbar" placement="start">
            <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              <Offcanvas.Title id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
                <span className="visually-hidden">SPF Nav Menu</span>
              </Offcanvas.Title>
            </Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                <StaticImage
                  src="../images/Spf-Brand-01.jpg"
                  alt="Brand Image"
                  layout="constrained"
                  placeholder="blurred"
                  height={50}
                  loading="eager"
                  className="offcanvas-brand"
                />
                <LinkWrapper>
                  <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                    Home
                  </Link>
                  <Link to="/#services" className="nav-link">
                    Services
                  </Link>
                  <Link to="/#faq" className="nav-link">
                    FAQ
                  </Link>
                  <Link to="/#contact" className="nav-link">
                    Contact
                  </Link>
                </LinkWrapper>
              </Nav>
            </Offcanvas.Body>
          </Navbar.Offcanvas>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

this is the build of the site:  https://pland.netlify.app/

Comment: Did you end up figuring this one out?

Answer (score 2):

All your links are to content on the same page, so using `Link` isn't necessary. Instead, replace these with regular anchor tags `<a href=''>Link</a>`

Secondly, the default behaviour of `Offcanvas` is that when the overlay is closed the focus is returned to where it was when the overlay was opened. That's why the page isn't scrolling to the correct position when the overlay is closed. To change this, you can pass in `restoreFocus={false}` prop to Offcanvas. [See Offcanvas API docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/offcanvas/#offcanvas-props).

Thirdly, to get the menu to close when a link is clicked, you should track whether the menu is open in state and add a toggle function to the `onClick` prop of each link, as well as the `Navbar.Toggle`.

```
const Navigation = () => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)
  }

  const handleClose = () => setMenuOpen(false)

  return(
   /** Omit code */
  
  <Navbar.Toggle
      aria-controls='offcanvasNavbar'
      aria-labelledby='offcanvasNavbarLabel'
      /** Add onClick toggle here */
      onClick={toggleMenu}
    />
    <Navbar.Offcanvas
      id='offcanvasNavbar'
      placement='start'
      /** Add these props */
      restoreFocus={false}
      show={menuOpen}
      onHide={handleClose}
    >
    
    /** omit code */

    <Nav className='justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3'>
        <a href='#services' className='nav-link' onClick={toggleMenu}>
           Services
        </a>
        <a href='#faq' className='nav-link' onClick={toggleMenu}>
           FAQ
        </a>
        {/** more links */}
     </Nav>
    /** omit code */
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the docs to automatically close: `collapseOnSelect`

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/navbar/#navbar-props

```html
    <Navbar
        collapseOnSelect
        as="nav"
        variant="light"
        fixed="top"
        expand={false}
        className="shadow"
      >
```

Comment: I think that setting is related to the navbar's collapse menu, I'm looking for a solution for the offcanvas, I have tried a solution using useState, but the problem I have there is with scrolling to the selected ID, it will begin scrolling toward it, but then will stop halfway as soon as the menu is closing.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [bernieu2](https://bernieu2) worked for me but I still had the half-way scroll problem. I patched that by creating a scrollTop function, and then passed it as a callback to the "onExit" attribute of the Offcanvas element:

const scrollTop = ()=>{window.scrollTo(0, 0)}

.
.
.
....... 
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap 5.3.2 and React v18. I solved this problem by adding `collapseOnSelect` prop to the  component.

```
 <Navbar
      collapseOnSelect
      data-bs-theme="dark"
      key={expand}
      expand={expand}
      className={`${styles.navBar}`}
    >
```